# Can successfully open modal when I need to but cannot close it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use React boostrap modal, I can successfully open it when i need to but I cannot close it. I have no idea what i am doing wrong.

my markup

````
```                <Modal show={this.props.show} >
                    <Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Title>Enter Log</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        Hello i am Modal!!!!!
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={() => {closeModal()}}  variant="primary"> Close </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>```
````

state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)   
    this.state = {
      closeModal: false
    }
}
```

Handler function:

```
const closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({closeModal: true}); 
}
```

Comment: According to the docs you're supposed to set `this.state.show` to `false`: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-live

Comment: I have trie the closeButton in the header which give a little cross on top right corner but when i click it it still does not close, I have also tried onHide ` className="addLog">
```                <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={() => {closeModal()}}>```

Comment: @John please have a look over my code . i think this would help you

Comment: Your modal renders if `{this.props.show}` is true, and your onClose function set `state.show` to false. You are using props vs state

Comment: @Drusto yes thats correct I use props to open `show` modal and trying to use state `closeModal` to close it

Comment: @John so, your condition should be the same to show the component and when close it

Comment: @John I think you can follow the below solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way,

```
const closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false});
}

<Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.closeModal} >
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Enter Log</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
       <p> Hello i am Modal!!!!! </p>
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={this.props.closeModal} variant="primary"> Close </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

refrence https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same condition to check if render the modal or not

You are using `props` to check if your modal should be rendered and when closing it, you are setting `state` to false.

If you want to use `props` you will need to update your props, using redux and dispatching an action or whatever

According to yor handleClose function, you will need to check `state` instead of `props` in the condition

`const closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({closeModal: true}); 
}`

```
<Modal show={this.props.show} >
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>Enter Log</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    Hello i am Modal!!!!!
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={() => this.closeModal()} variant="primary"> Close </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
```